# Greater of two variables in mySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to write a query that returns a single date value, that value being whichever of two columns is the most recent.

So if I have a table with values a, b, date1, date2 I want something like:

```
SELECT a, b, (Greater of date1 and date2) as date FROM...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: There seems to be two solid answers here, is one better than the other? Would they both work with timestamps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function .

```
SELECT a, b, GREATEST(date1,date2) as date FROM...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use an [IF statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if-statement.html)

```
SELECT a, b, IF(date1>date2, date1, date2) as date
```

Answer (score 0):

Just us the [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function...

```
SELECT a, b, 
    IF (date1 > date2, date1, date2) AS 'date'
FROM yourtable
```

... or compare it with [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest):

```
SELECT a, b, 
    GREATEST(date1, date2) AS 'date'
FROM yourtable
```